# Adding CSV Import to a ROR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am adding a CSV import for bulk orders in my online ordering application. Basically what I am looking to do is to create a cart out of the CSV data.

I created an imports_controller:

```
require 'csv'
 class ImportsController < ApplicationController  
def csv_import

num_imported = 0
num_failed = 0

CSV.foreach(params[:dump][:file].csv) do |row|
c = CsvImport.new(
  cart_items: row[1],
  cart_items_quantity: row[2],
  cart_items_price: row[3],
  cart_items_description: row[4],
  cart_items_upc: row[5],
  cart_items_sku: row[6]
)
if c.save
  num_imported += 1
else
  num_failed += 1
end
end

flash.now[:message] = "CSV Import Successful, #{num_imported} new records added to data base. #{num_failed} failed to import."
  end
end
```

it is generating the following error in the log:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant ImportsController::CsvImport):
app/controllers/imports_controller.rb:11:in `block in csv_import'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1761:in `each'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1202:in `block in foreach'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1340:in `open'
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1201:in `foreach'
app/controllers/imports_controller.rb:10:in `csv_import'
```

The CSV Import form is in thequick order page:

```
    <div class="cart_items column_headers" id="cart_items_add">
        <div class="cart_items_description">
            <div>
                <h3>Import CSV Order</h3>                                
                 <% form_for :dump, :url=>{:controller=>"imports", :action=>"csv_import"}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| -%>
                     <table">
                       <tr>
                         <td>
                          <label for="dump_file">
                            Select a CSV File :
                          </label>
                         </td>
                         <td >
                           <%= f.file_field :file -%>
                         </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                         <td colspan='2'>
                           <%= submit_tag 'Submit' -%>
                         </td>
                       </tr>
                     </table>
                    <% end -%>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
<% total = 0 %>
    <% if !@cart_contents.blank? && !@cart_contents.count.blank? %>
        <% @cart_contents.each do |item| %>
            <%= render :partial => "my_cart/partials/cart_item", :locals => { :cart_item => item } %>
            <% total += (item[:price].to_f * item[:quantity].to_i) %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %> <!-- if cart is not empty -->

    <div class="cart_items">
        <div class="cart_items_description">
            <br style="clear:both;" />
        </div>
        <div class="cart_items_quantity" style="padding-top: 6px;">
            <p>Total:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cart_items_price">
            <br style="clear:both;" />
        </div>
        <div class="cart_items_total">
            <p>
                <%= text_field_tag("order_total", '%.2f' % total, :readonly => true, :size => "10", :class => "readonly", :style => "color: #C31E22; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;") %>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart_items">
        <div class="cart_items_full">
            <a href="/products"><%= image_tag "/images/continue_shopping.png" %></a>
            <a href="/my-cart"><%= image_tag "/images/proceed_to_cart.png" %></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
<% end %>

*my app running really old version of Ruby and Rails (Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.2)
```

The current issue is

```
 CSV.foreach(File.open params[:dump][:file]) do |row|
```

and why that the param is not being set. My thought is that is has to do with the form call of

```
<%= f.file_field :file -%>
```

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: I am seeing  `undefined method `tempfile' for #<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20150319-29004-1xhki29>`in the error log is this an issue with where it is trying to save the file?

Comment: the only thing that I am seeing in the error log now is: `NoMethodError (undefined method `csv' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/imports_controller.rb:10:in `csv_import'
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.1) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request`  I have tried every combination I can think of still no luck...any ideas that I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Your form is submitting to the `csv_import` action.  Your controller defines a `csv_import=` method.  Not sure what else is in your controller or what that `csv_import=` method is for, but you need a `csv_import` method in your controller that can process the request.

Something like this perhaps:

```
def csv_import

  num_imported = 0
  num_failed = 0

  CSV.foreach(params[:file].tempfile) do |row|
    c = CsvImport.new(
      cart_items: row[1],
      cart_items_quantity: row[2],
      cart_items_price: row[3],
      cart_items_description: row[4],
      cart_items_upc: row[5],
      cart_items_sku: row[6]
    )
    if c.save
      num_imported += 1
    else
      num_failed += 1
    end
  end

  flash.now[:message] = "CSV Import Successful, #{num_imported} new records added to data base. #{num_failed} failed to import."
end
```

Comment: ok I added the method back that I had used previously and this generates the following log error: NoMethodError (undefined method `csv' for #<ImportsController:0xb0520e8>):  on this line:  csv::Reader.parse(File.open('file.csv')){|row| puts row}

Comment: Ok. It's `CSV` not `csv`.  But there are other issues too like where does `@parsed_file` come from, etc.? I don't know if this will fix it, but see my update for what I think needs to happen.

Comment: You'll need to see what is actually being sent to your controller.  Sounds like `params[:file]` isn't the actual parameter for your uploaded file.

Comment: No. You need to figure out what the parameter name is and why it's not being set.  I may also be wrong about `tempfile`, but there is a way to read the temp file placed on disk.

Comment: is it possible that the reason the reason that the param is not being set due to the way that <%= f.file_field :file -%> is called in the form?

Comment: Probably.  Hrm... might be `params[:dump][:file]`.  Really though just look at the log file.  It will list it out.

Comment: I tried using params[:dump][:file], params[:dump][:file].tempfile and then params[:dump].tempfile with the last resulting in...`NoMethodError (undefined method `tempfile' for {"tempfile"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20150326-2522-1vgenl0>}:HashWithIndifferentAccess):  app/controllers/imports_controller.rb:10:in `csv_import'` is this still the same issue of the param not being set or is this with the csv file itself? Also I am not seeing a way to find the param from the log file unless it is somewhere else?