# ROR import csv file: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import, ibm-midrange

I am adding an import CSV to an online ordering app previous question include [ROR import csv file no method error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370626/ror-import-csv-file-no-method-error), [Adding CSV Import to a ROR application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105381/adding-csv-import-to-a-ror-application). Thank you to those that have helped in the other questions.

the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `build_from_csv' for #<Class:0x9ddd82c>):
   app/controllers/imports_controller.rb:14:in `block in imports'
   /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1761:in `each'
   /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1370:in `parse'
   app/controllers/imports_controller.rb:10:in `imports'
```

the imports_controller:

```
require 'csv'
class ImportsController < ApplicationController    

def imports
logger.info "File loaded"
infile = params[:dump][:infile].read

n, errors = 0, []
@archive = []
CSV.parse(infile) do |row|
  n += 1
  # SKIP: header i.e. first row OR blank row
  next if n == 1 or row.join.blank?
  imports = Order.build_from_csv(row)
  if imports.valid?
    imports.save
    @archive << row
  else
    errors << row
  end
end
logger.info errors
flash[:success] = "The CSV imported successfully" 

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @archive }
  end
end
```

originally I had a models/imports.rb but I moved it to models/order.rb since I am trying to add the csv date to that table:

```
 def self.build_from_csv(row)
      #last_level = (row[5].downcase == "yes"
     orders = Orders.new(:imports => "#{row[0]}}",
                            :cart_items => "#{row[1]}",
                            :cart_items_quantity => "#{row[2]}",
                            :cart_items_price => "#{row[3]}",
                            :cart_items_description => "#{row[4]}",
                            :cart_items_upc => "#{row[5]}",
                            :cart_items_sku => "#{row[6]}")
                           # :last_level=> last_level)
           return imports
 end
```

for the line with the error:

```
imports = Order.build_from_csv(row)
```

I have tried

```
imports = Imports.build_from_csv(row)
```

I used Order since that is that table that the cart items get inserted into but no luck. I also tried:

```
imports = CSV.build_from_csv(row)
```

...

```
imports = Infile.build_from_csv(row)
```

and that caused an Uninitialized Constant. I am open to suggestions for other things to try, Thanks again for the help!

Comment: `Orders`? You have only one mention of that class in your question, and I strongly suspect that it's a typo. That would explain why `Order` failed to get defined and why did you get that error. On top of that, if you're defining a class method on `Order`, it's better to reference it inside as `self.class`. DRY.

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion. now it is looking for an imports view  
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template imports/imports.erb in view path  - I have put the view on another page (quick_order)do I have rename the class?

Comment: Not really. The comment near `format.html` is quite misleading there -- it picks the name of action by default, method name, which is `imports`. Huh, would you mind skimming through a more general tutorial, like M. Hartl's book "Rails Tutorial"?